# Foreach loop is running n times

Tags: php, loops, foreach

```
foreach($CarAdList as $CarAd)
{
    echo($msg .= '<tr><td>'.$CarAd->getCarAdID().'</td><td>' .$CarAd->getBrandText().'</td><td>' .$CarAd->getDescription(). '</td><td><a href="status.php?id='.$CarAd->getCarAdID().'"><img src="../images/active.png" /></a></td><td><img src="../images/delete.png" width="30px" /></td></tr>');
}
```

e.g,
the number of rows =38

n= the number of rows * the number of rows--

it is running n times

so its displaying

```
5
5
4
5
4
3
5
4
3
2
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: What is your question? How many times did you expect it to run? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo($msg .= 'somecontent')` is a pretty strange construct. Either you want to concat the value and output it in the end, or you do the output immediately.

```
foreach($a as $b) {
   echo $b;
}
```

or

```
$var = '';
foreach($a as $b) {
   $var .= $b;
}
echo $var
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop only runs the requested amount of times, but your output does not match. That is because you're adding text to `$msg` and at the same time `echo` it.

Either construct `$msg` in the loop and echo it later, or echo without concatting the previous result, like so:

```
foreach($CarAdList as $CarAd)
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$CarAd->getCarAdID().'</td><td>' .$CarAd->getBrandText().'</td><td>' .$CarAd->getDescription(). '</td><td><a href="status.php?id='.$CarAd->getCarAdID().'"><img src="../images/active.png" /></a></td><td><img src="../images/delete.png" width="30px" /></td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: @OP: To clarify: The first time, assuming `$msg` is empty, the code is outputting the first row.  The second, because you're tacking the second row onto the existing `$msg` (which already has the first row) and displaying the whole thing, it's outputting the first *two* rows.  The third, the first *three*.  And so on.